# How do I bring back the icons that indicate git status in the Windows shell?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In Windows explorer, the green checkie icon for repositories that are up-to-date and the red mark for those that aren't don't show anymore.

How do I bring them back?

Please see the pictures attached. For e.g. I do have some untracked files in the repository named Temp.

[image]

However, none of the folders have the green or red icons that display the git repository status.

[image]

They used to be there earlier. They suddenly disappeared a few weeks ago.

I am using 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: May we ask what caused the icons to disappear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers and windows10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697737/shelliconoverlayidentifiers-and-windows10)

Comment: you have too many shell overlay icons registered. disable some to get under the 15 icon limit

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't know what shell overlay icons mean. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: the status overlays you miss are called shell overlay and there is a hardcoded limit of 15. if you use dropbox, onedrive you already reach the limit

Comment: Than you. Would you like to put that down as an answer? It will help someone else who has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, I had the Dropbox ones and the GoogleDrive ones appearing before the Totoise ones in order. I un-installed both GoogleDrive and Dropbox, even restarted my machine but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: Please see https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#ovlnotshowing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseGit Icon Overlays not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588130/tortoisegit-icon-overlays-not-showing)

Comment: @MrTux Thank you. That is very useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution to this was provided by @magicandre1981 in the comments to this question. Here is my attempt to explain the solution.

It appears that application such as Tortoise Git, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. that present different icons in front of Windows explorer files and folders do so by creating an overlay on top of the regular icons that Windows draws. Apparently, the application registers these overlays and Windows redraws each overlay once it has finished the basic drawing of file system objects.

However, Windows imposes a limit on the number of overlays it will honor. Any number of applications can register any number of overlays with Windows. But Windows will only pick the first 15 overlays registered with it and re-draw them. The rest will be ignored.

The Windows registry maintains the order and number of overlays registered. Specifically, the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers** has this list as seen in the picture below.

[image]

An explanation of this can also be found on [this web page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youhana/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools/).

As can be seen Dropbox and Google Drive had already registered more than 15 overlays in total, which was why Windows never got a chance to honor the overlays registered by Tortoise Git on my machine.

I uninstalled Dropbox and Google Drive as I didn't use their sync feature much.

[image]

I didn't see any change so I restarted my machine. I still didn't see any change but after about 30 minutes or so of restarting my machine, the icons were restored to normal, i.e. I started seeing the Tortoise git status for my repositories just fine.

[image]

Comment: ok, nice to see that you got it working now. but remember to edit it for **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers** to see them in 32bit applications like Visual Studio

Comment: Rather than uninstall apps you can change the number of spaces in front of the name since the list is alphabetically sorted.  So changing "  OneDrive1" to "OneDrive1" bumps it down the list.  Then use task manager to restart Explorer and the icons are there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem has to do with pathing in Windows. If you put your cloned repository in a well known (directory within the path) directory the green check mark shows up. That is how I have been able to solve this issue. But the issue came back later. We ended up reinstalling TortoiseGit

Answer (score 0):

Updates to registry fix the problem, HOWEVER, restarting the explorer did NOT restore my icons... but after **logging off and logging back** in, then the icons where restored.