# Different icon overlays for TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit

Tags: icons, windows-10, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I have installed both, TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit, on my Windows 10 system. To be able to more easily discern between Git- and SVN-based projects, I figured it would be best to use different icon overlays for both clients. Unfortunately, when I change the icon overlay in e.g. TortoiseSVN, the overlays for git-repositories also change to the icon set I selected in TortoiseSVN.

Is there a way to use different icon overlays for TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. Because [Windows only supports 15 overlay icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41702234/1466046), the TortoiseXYZ projects share the same overlay icon handler to reduce the number of installed overlay icon handlers.

Comment: That's a real shame.

Comment: submit a request in feedback hub to allow more overlays in a newer Windows 10 Future Update (1803, 1809, 1903)